Do quests beyond the Prologue quests give out Character EXP directly as a reward?
Everyone says that Character EXP can be gotten from quests, but usually they're referring to the Character Development Item that gives Character EXP upon application of Mora.
Are there non-Prologue quests that give out Character EXP directly, when completed?
